# Gulp - Visual Studio 2017 - MSB3073 The command "gulp postbuild" exited with code 1

Tags: visual-studio, gulp, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017 I am getting error `MSB3073 The command "gulp postbuild" exited with code 1`.

In my gulp file I have:

```
gulp.task('postbuild', function() {
   //...
});
```

On command line I get error when I try `gulp loc`:

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\semver\semver.js:281
throw new TypeError('Invalid Version: ' + version);
^

TypeError: Invalid Version: undefinedypeError('Invalid Version: ' + version);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I just needed to add an environment variable `NODE_PATH` pointing to `%AppData%\npm\node_modules`